# Filtering out mentions in the Twitter Timeline plugin for EE1

Tags: expressionengine

When using the [Twitter Timeline plugin](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/twitter_timeline/) in EE1, is there a way to filter out mentions from the list of tweets that it outputs?

I only want to output tweets that don't start off as a reply to another user, in order to avoid conversations appearing in a website's Twitter feed.

Thanks,

Ste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Tweetline](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tweetline) for this in the past. It's quite a bit more flexible than the Twitter Timeline plugin and you can easily filter out mentions and retweets.

---

**Edit with EE1 fix:** Fortunately the Twitter API (even this old version) supports parameters for retweets and replies, so adding in params for those is very simple. Look for this on line 82:

```php
$TMPL->log_item("Using '{$timeline}' Twitter Timeline {$log_extra}");
```

Underneath that add the following:

```php
// toggle retweets and replies

if ($TMPL->fetch_param('replies') == 'off')
{
    $this->parameters['exclude_replies'] = TRUE;
}

if ($TMPL->fetch_param('retweets') == 'on')
{
    $this->parameters['include_rts'] = TRUE;
}
```

You can then use code like this in your template:

```
{exp:twitter_timeline screen_name="someguy" limit="1" replies="off" retweets="off"}
```

Due to the way the API's setup it looks as though replies are included by default and retweets aren't. It's worth noting this too, from the [API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline):

> The value of count is best thought of as a limit to the number of tweets to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been applied. We include retweets in the count, even if include_rts is not supplied. It is recommended you always send include_rts=1 when using this API method.

Comment: Thanks Dom. That looks perfect, but it's EE2 only. I'll start using that in my EE2 sites instead of the Twitter Timeline plugin from now on though. I'll just use a JS solution for this EE1 site as it seems there's no EE1 plugins that do this.

Comment: Somehow I missed the EE1 references in your question. Hold off on the JS though - I've got to implement a twitter feed on a client's old EE1 site in the next week or so and I'm going to want to hide replies as well. I'll see if I can put together a quick patch.

Comment: I've updated my post with a patch that'll let you toggle retweets and replies. I haven't tested it much yet but it seems to do the trick.